# Проставить максимальное значение точек между span

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день. Как сделать чтобы имена полей "Рынок, сегмент итд." находились на максимальном удалении от значения и между ними проставлялись точки, как на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] В один span или div не могу их обернуть oracle jet не дает данные приходящие из JSON внести в блок уже с каким то текстом, поэтому имя и значение разбил по блокам.

```css
.oj-flex {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.oj-xl-6 {
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 50%;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.one {
background-color: red;
}
.two {
background-color: #00a13b;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent oj-flex">
<div class="oj-xl-6 oj-lg-6 oj-md-6 one">
          <div class="oj-flex">
            <span class="oj-sm-12 oj-flex-item">Рынок.......
            <span class="modul">123 имя рынка</span></span></div>
          <div class="oj-flex">
          <span class="oj-sm-12">Сегмент.......
            <span class="modul"></span>123 имя сегмента</span></div>
            <div class="oj-flex">
          <span class="oj-sm-12">Категория.......
            <span class="modul">имя категории в две строки</span></span></div>
              <div class="oj-flex">
          <span class="oj-sm-12">Семья.......
            <span class="modul"> имя семьи</span></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="oj-xl-6 oj-lg-6 oj-md-6 two">
          <div class="oj-flex">
            <span class="oj-sm-12 oj-flex-item">Основной штрихкод.......
            <span class="modul">123232543543</span></span></div>
          <div class="oj-flex">
            <span class="oj-sm-12 oj-flex-item">GICA.......
            <span class="modul">АС</span></span></div>
          <div class="oj-flex">
            <span class="oj-sm-12 oj-flex-item">METI.......
            <span class="modul"></span>1</span></div>
          <div class="oj-flex">
            <span class="oj-sm-12 oj-flex-item">Lillapois.......
            <span class="modul">1</span></span></div>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Ну если Вам известна максимальная длина строки и длина входящей строки - вычитайте и рисуйте циклом - имхо, вполне рабочий велосипед с костылями)

Comment: Разные мониторы разные размеры блоков, ширина родительского блока в процентах. к тому же значения всегда разные, они динамические

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я тут как-то рисовал. Может быть будет полезно:

```css
.left {
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 0px
}

.left,
.right {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan Thorn — How to Cheat in Unity 5 Tips and tricks</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan Thorn — Mastering Unity Scripting</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Joseph Hocking — Unity in Action (Джозеф Хокинг — Unity в действии)</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Кенни Ламмерс — Шейдеры и эффекты в Unity</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan R. Stagner — Unity Multiplayer Games</span>
  <span class="right">3.4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Alan Zucconi, Kenneth Lammers — Unity 5.x Shaders and Effects Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Chris Dickinson — Unity 5 Game Optimization</span>
  <span class="right">5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Jeremy Gibson — Introduction to Game Design, Prototyping, and Development</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Matt Smith — Unity 5.x Cookbook</span>
  <span class="right">4.5/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Ryan Henson Creighton — Unity 3D Game Development</span>
  <span class="right">3.9/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Sue Blackman — Beginning 3D Game Development with Unity</span>
  <span class="right">4/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Terry Norton — Learning C# by Developing Games with Unity 3D (Veeeeeeeeerrry Beginner's Guide)</span>
  <span class="right">3.7/5</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="left">Venita Pereira — Learning Unity 2D Game Development by Example</span>
  <span class="right">3/5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое это то что нужно=)